# How to remove elements with NA

Tags: r

I am using this function to return a list of pairs from a data frame:

```
f <- function(x, n) sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)[1:n]


lapply(mypairlist, f, n = 3)
```

An example output:

```
V18, NA     A12, NA     S21, NA 
290         155         45
```

I do not want the function to return pairs that have NA in them. I'm sure it's really simple but I can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My input data looks like this:

```
ID       TopPair
123      V18, NA
124      V18, NA
125      V18, V21
126      A12, NA
127      A12, NA
128      V18, NA
129      A57, B43
```

And I want V18, V21 and A57, B43 returned rather than pairs with NAs.

Comment: Please provide an example of your input data.

Comment: What is the input dataset?

Comment: How about `df1[!grepl("NA", df1$TopPair),]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the 'TopPair' is a string column, we can use `grep` to get the index of `NA` elements

```
df1[!grepl("NA", df1$TopPair),]
#   ID  TopPair
#3 125 V18, V21
#7 129 A57, B43
```